# Python Turtle: How to use the write function to join an integer and a string with the integer coming from a list

Tags: python, string, list, integer, turtle-graphics

So, I'm trying to get the grade to be able to print a percentage sign in the exact same line as to when I write the grade.

The aim is to have it print: 45% for the first example.

```
from turtle import *
  grades = [45, 42, 13, 98, 82]
  write(grades[0],'%')
```

When I run this code both the grade and percentage sign gets printed on top of each other. How do I get the grade and the percentage sign, side by side without the two overlapping?

Comment: By the way, it would be `grades[0]` to get the first item by index, as in Python the indexes start at `0`.

Comment: May I suggest http://pythonturtle.org/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using string `format` method:

```
write("{0}%".format(grades[1]))
```